# JQuery: display and subdivide alphabetically database retrieved elements

Tags: jquery, alphabetical

I retrieved a list of names from a database and I would display them alphabetically ordered in a jsp page.

In the top of the page, I would to have a clickable alphabet such that by clicking on a letter the user goes to the right section.

Is there a jquery plugin to achieve this? or?

**EDIT**

A B C .... (A is a link if there are elements which begins with A, etc)

A
apple

B
banana
book

C
...

**EDIT 2**

I'm trying to use the jquery listnav plugin, [here](http://www.ihwy.com/labs/Demos/Current/jquery-listnav-plugin.aspx)

In the jsp file, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.listnav-2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#myList').listnav();
    });
</script>
```

and then:

```
<div id="myList-nav"></div>
<ul id="myList">
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
<li>four</li>
<li>five</li>
</ul>
```

The plugin is correctly loaded, but firebug gives the message:

```
TypeError: $(...).listnav is not a function
error source line: $('#myList').listnav();
```

I don't understand where I'm wronging.

Comment: can you retrieve from database order by name?

Comment: @PSR: I think so, but I would to subdivide them (I've edited my question)

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, you want to divide the data based on the first letter and then allow the user to be able to filter a set of results by that letter, is that right?

This isn't a jquery plugin and somebody else could probably write something a lot better but I've written a JSFiddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6WeBW/1/).

The basic way it works is that you pass it an array of strings and it will read through that array and split the data into individual arrays for each letter in the alphabet that it finds from the first letter of each string. It will then create a button for each of them and on the click of that button display only that data.

It's really just a case of using `for` loops quite a lot so it may be extremely slow to load, but once it's loaded it should perform well.

An alternative would be to iterate through the whole array each time picking only items that match the first letter that was clicked, this would cut down load time but would be much slower for general use.

EDIT - I've created a modular version of this now, so you can simply instantiate a new instance of `AlphaSplit` with your array and then call the .create() method on it. You can see a working version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6WeBW/2/).

Comment: I woult to achiede something like this (http://www.ihwy.com/Labs/Demos/Current/jquery-listnav-plugin.aspx)[this]

Comment: what is missing from the JSFiddle example that you want?